# Сoncatenation of tables with matching of contents in columns

Tags: python, pandas

Column Id contains ID of sample 
Column "before" contains what was before modification 
Column "after" contains what happens after the modification

I want to merge tables by ID, but to have the same values in the "before" and "after" columns opposite each other.
Sometimes table 1 contains nothing in the "before" column.
Sometimes table 2 contains nothing in the "after" column.
Sometimes "before" and "after" have a partial overlap or do not overlap sometimes a full overlap.

**table_one**

| Id | before |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | a |
| id1 | b |
| id1 | c |
| id3 | d |
| id4 | a |
| id4 | b |

**table_two**

| Id | after |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | b |
| id1 | d |
| id2 | c |
| id4 | a |
| id4 | b |

**concatinated_table**

| Id | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | a | none |
| id1 | b | b |
| id1 | c | none |
| id1 | none | d |
| id2 | none | c |
| id3 | d | none |
| id4 | a | a |
| id4 | b | b |

Code to reproduce problem

```
id_ = ['id1', 'id1']
before = ['a','b']
after = ['b','c']

before = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id_, before)), columns =['id_', 'before'])
after = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id_, after)), columns =['id_', 'after'])
pd.concat([before, after])
```

[image: screen]

Comment: How do you define partial overlap? How do you define full overlap?  What is rationale for your expected result having the last row after value moved to first row after position?  What is definition of the Column with 1033's and 512's in it?  Why isn't this column shown in your sample dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `output=pd.concat([before, after], axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

To arrive at your `output`, you could use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

before_data = {'Id': ['id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id3', 'id4', 'id4'],
               'before': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']}
before = pd.DataFrame(before_data)

after_data = {'Id': ['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id4', 'id4'], 
              'after': ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'b']}
after = pd.DataFrame(after_data)

res = before.merge(after, left_on=['Id','before'], right_on=['Id','after'], 
                   how='outer').sort_values('Id').reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)

    Id before after
0  id1      a   NaN
1  id1      b     b
2  id1      c   NaN
3  id1    NaN     d
4  id2    NaN     c
5  id3      d   NaN
6  id4      a     a
7  id4      b     b

# same result as your `output`, at least after changing "none" to `np.nan`:
output.replace(to_replace='none', value=np.nan, inplace=True)
output.equals(res) # True
```

Comment: You're welcome. If the answers offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question (and consider upvoting).